# urldecode increase a string length

Tags: php, drupal, urldecode

Hi Friends below is my url that i want to decode.

```
http://www.example.com?sectionId=11&section=--%2520Cspr%2520%232+%26amp%3B+Dsrenu
```

below is my php code.

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['section']."<br>";
    $selectedSection = urldecode($_REQUEST['section']);
    var_dump($selectedSection);
    echo '<br>';
    var_dump('-- Cspr #2 & Dsrenu');
    echo '<br>';
?>

output
----------------------------------------------------------
--%20Cspr%20#2 & Dsrenu
string(23) "-- Cspr #2 & Dsrenu" 
string(19) "-- Cspr #2 & Dsrenu"
```

the `$_REQUEST` string length is 23 and normal same string i add directly into `var_dump` that string length is 19 i don't know why and i can't find any solution for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be a unicode/encoding issue?

Comment: You can check length of string with `strlen()`

Answer (score 0):

The length of string is 23 only but browser displays %26 as "&" for you thats why your length is increased.

If you want same strlen results then you must pass "--+Cspr+%232+%26+Dsrenu" in your url.

Thanks

Comment: i am not pass anything in URL. i just simply "-- Cspr #2 & Dsrenu" string into url it is automatically convert into "--%2520Cspr%2520%232+%26amp%3B+Dsrenu"

Comment: You cant pass & in url straight away because php will make it another GET variable. You must always use urlencode for passing special characters or & in value

Comment: Yes, i know but i used the Drupal framework and drupal automatically urlencode encode URL. so i just give a string as a parameter. thanks

Comment: You can give encoded string as a parameter to the l() or url(). for reference check like this echo var_dump(htmlspecialchars_decode($selectedSection));